# QFileIconProvider (PyQt5) crashes on macOs Catalina

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to create an icon using QFileIconProvider on PyQt5 on macOs Catalina:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileIconProvider
ip = QFileIconProvider()
ip.icon(QFileIconProvider.Folder)
```

the former code yields:

```
zsh: segmentation fault
```

I am using python 3.7

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of Qt's objects require a QXApplication to be created, and that's the case for QFileIconProvider:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileIconProvider

app = QApplication([])
ip = QFileIconProvider()
icon = ip.icon(QFileIconProvider.Folder)
print(icon, icon.isNull())
```